# Why are table cells displayed differently in different browsers?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Here is a screenshot showing the problem:

[image]

Here is the CSS I am using:

```
#board table {
    background: #eef0ff;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #475476;
}

#board td {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #cfd7ee;
}
```

How can I makes the cells the same size in diferent browsers? Does anyone know why Opera and Firefox tighten the cells?

Comment: It's the default styling. Things like margins and padding. This is why some people like to use a reset file. Such as this one by meyer. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: And some people like to just override the relevant default styling, finding out the exact cause without adding a whole new replacement of defaults to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use a [CSS reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset), or set some of your own defaults for table margins, padding and other elements in your design.

A CSS reset (either yours or a third party one) will ensure all browsers have a similar starting point, regarding styles, as the different browsers do not have the same style defaults on different elements.

Additionally, as @thirtydot says in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181457/why-are-table-cells-displayed-differently-in-different-browsers/8181672#8181672), some browsers will ignore the height of a  completely empty table cell, such as `<td></td>`. To ensure it is not ignored, you should add some content to these cells, a good choice being the non break space - `&nbsp;`, in this manner: `<td>&nbsp;</td>`.

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but I don't think your answer is correct in this case. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: @thirtydot - Possibly. I'd say we both got _part_ of the answer.

Comment: Well, not really. No common CSS reset will fix this problem. Sure, a reset might help with other inconsistencies, but it won't fix **this problem**.

Comment: Guys, not one answer was not helpful. Neither <td>&nbsp;</td> nor the reset.css.

Comment: @user1048261 - You are using a double negative, so your statement is very confusing. Were these helpful or not? If not, what's still happening that shouldn't?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. Reset and <td>&nbsp;</td> doesn't solve the problem. I'm using reset by Eric Mayer.

Comment: @user1048261 - Great. And is your problem solved? If not, can you describe what's still not working?

Comment: @user1048261 - Give the `TR` a `height` as well.

Comment: I set the tr height on 2 pixels more than td and the cells are same now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your cells are all empty, right? `<td></td>`?

One fix that will definitely work is to stick an `&nbsp;` in each cell: `<td>&nbsp;</td>`.

For some other ideas, see: [CSS table, table-cell height issue in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004941/css-table-table-cell-height-issue-in-firefox/5004985#5004985)

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted, I'm almost certainly *correct*. Compare in Firefox/Chrome this: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/L3EQJ/

Comment: I havent down voted you, but I looked at your jsfiddle and the two cells are exactly the same. Also, this answer is not a solution to the question. I hope this has helped in reducing your certainty

Comment: @Abe Petrillo: This *is* a solution to the problem. In the original question, the cells look fine in Chrome + IE, and are squished in Opera + Firefox. Guess what: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3aoQF.png. ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 0):

First reset your HTML code default properties like padding, margin, height, width.etc.., then you apply your style to work

Better reset css is [Eric Mayer's](http://www.cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/)