# Firefox Issue: Relative-positioned Table-cell Fails to Serve as Parent

Tags: html, css, firefox

I've discovered an interesting layout issue seemingly present only in Firefox.

***Elements with `display:table-cell;` fail to serve as the positional parent for descendants with `position:absolute;`.***

That is, I've been surprised to learn that Firefox has issues absolutely positioning a little icon critter into the corner of a table-cell'd element like the other browsers.

***[jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseMoskal/BnUw4/)***

---

#### Desired Result *(Chrome)*:

[image: chrome perfect output]

#### Firefox Result:

[image: firefox problematic output]

---

**Interestingly, even IE8 produces the desired result.**

  *What's your favorite workaround?*

Comment: when in doubt, google it out..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004941/css-table-table-cell-height-issue-in-firefox

Comment: @user2712605: *seems* totally unrelated.

Comment: Yeah that question is totally unrelated. Here are some actually related questions: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629326/position-relative-in-firefox), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148041/does-firefox-support-position-relative-on-table-elements). Here's the massive Firefox bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63895. It's a bit of a running joke at this point...

Answer (score 0):

So far, I've found the lame-and-obvious solution.

***The desired result can be achieved in Firefox by adding a lame wrapper `<div>` with `display:block;` and `position:relative` applied within the table-cell.***

***[Wrapper Solution jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseMoskal/zHkya/)***

Hoping somebody can find a solution that doesn't require me to meddle with the DOM just for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position) clearly states:

> The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

Being undefined, Firefox will just ignore your position-relative. Thus your `.container` becomes the *nearest positioned ancestor* and is used for the absolutely-positioned `.icon` elements.

So, as it turns out that both implementations, Firefox and Chrome, are right/wrong the same. You simply cannot rely on undefined behavior.
In the end, you need to use that wrapper you seem to dread to be spec- and browser-compatible.