# Why is Firefox computing incorrect div dimensions?

Tags: firefox

I have a webpage with a table arrangement made from divs. On load I use jQuery to calculate the best dimensions based on the available space. It works perfectly fine in other browsers, but for some reason Firefox adds height to certain divs.

I'm using Firefox 50.1.0 for Linux Mint - 1.0. It only has default add-ons and extensions.

Here are the computed values...

[image: computed values]

...and here is the rendered HTML, along with the relevant part of the HTML doc.

[image: rendered html]

I have absolutely no idea where Firefox is getting the extra 18 pixels in height. Outputting the jQuery values show that the correct dimensions are being calculated, and they appear in the HTML. Can anybody tell me why this is happening, and how to stop it?

Here are all the values computed for the div..

```
border-bottom-color: rgb(77, 76, 75);
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-image-outset: 0 0 0 0;
border-image-repeat: stretch stretch;
border-image-slice: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1 1 1 1;
border-left-color: rgb(77, 76, 75);
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-right-color: rgb(77, 76, 75);
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-top-color: rgb(77, 76, 75);
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1px;
display: table-cell;
height: 59px;
width: 41px;
-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
-moz-border-left-colors: none;
-moz-border-right-colors: none;
-moz-border-top-colors: none;
```

**Edit**

It looks like it might have something to do with the display value table, and its variations.

The layout is like this...

```
<div style="display:table">
    <div style="display:table-row">
        <div style="display:table-cell"></div>
        <div style="display:table-cell"></div>
        ...etc
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-row">
        <div style="display:table-cell"></div>
        <div style="display:table-cell"></div>
        ...etc
    </div>
    ...etc
</div>
```

Comment: It probably has something to do with the fact that the div is being displayed as a table-cell, but I can't quite comment beyond that.

Comment: @BoltClock I just noticed that myself and edited my question. I'll play around and read up on that display option. Hopefully I can find something. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS table, table-cell height issue in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004941/css-table-table-cell-height-issue-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

So I eventually found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5004985/2986364) answer to a question asked nearly five years ago. You need to add a `&nbsp;` in every div that uses `display:table-cell`.